# Change a ListView Item's Height based off it's location on the screen

Tags: android, android-listview, scaling

I'm trying to make a ListView where the size of the items in the list view are enlarged as they scroll up. I have been looking for ways to do this butI'm having trouble finding how to modify the listView's scroll.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020859/change-height-of-a-listview-dynamicallyandroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working at it for a while I made some discoveries. Resizing the Size of each item is computationaly rediculousely expensive. So don't, do it once.

This lead to a new approach. Instead I resize the things inside the view. This has the same effect but is drastically faster.

This can be done be creating a custom listItemView that extends ListView and overriding the drawChild method.

Hope this helps anyone who tries something similar.